# Plotting contour lines between a certain range with an accuracy of contour lines to a certain decimal points

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour

I want to plot contour lines with an accuracy of seven to eight decimal points. I have used `ax.clabel(contour, inline= True, inline_spacing = -1,fmt = '%1.7f',fontsize=8)` to get 7 decimal points.
I am getting this kind of contour lines:
[image]

but I want it to show something like this where contour lines of near about 0.99, 1.01 are shown with 7 to 8 digits of accuracy and I also want to plot 0.99999999 ≤ |G| ≤ 1.00000001
[image]

Following are the blocks of code.

```
khmax = np.arange(0,np.pi,0.01)
Ncmax = np.arange(0,np.pi,0.01)
[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(Ncmax,khmax)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

```
contour = plt.contour(X,Y,mod_G)
ax.set_title('magnitude of G')
ax.set_xlabel('Ncmax')
ax.set_ylabel('khmax')
ax.clabel(contour, inline= True, inline_spacing = -1,fmt = '%1.7f',fontsize=8)
plt.show()
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way will be to just set the `levels` keyword argument of `contour`:

```
contour = plt.contour(X,Y,mod_G, levels = [0.99999999, 0.999999995, 1.0, 1.000000005, 1.00000001])
```

or whatever exact levels you want (note that every contour line drawn will have to be included in the `levels` list. I might recommend creating it algorithmically, rather than writing it out by hand as I did above)

Comment: I actually don't know what levels should I enter because the levels could be 0.9998, 0.99000 so on and so forth. I just need a few contour lines in the range given in the question. I used ` levels = np.arange(0.99,1.000000001,0.001)` but the contour lines appear to be very clustered. If you could suggest something or is there any way that area having contour lines with values equal to 1 or lesser than1 gets shaded or marked?

Comment: You could also try setting `levels` to an integer, and it will automatically populate with evenly-spaced contours (evenly spaced, as in the values of the contours are evenly spaced)

Comment: Setting integral values gives me contour lines that are equally spaced but can this same thing be done between two values? I referred to the documentation of matplotlib, which said that " If an int n, use MaxNLocator, which tries to automatically choose no more than n+1 "nice" contour levels between vmin and vmax." I don't know how to set the values of vmin and vmax.

Comment: Hmm. Have a look at the documentation for the [`Locator`](matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html) class. The `LinearLocator` may be helpful, or just the generic one, or even `MaxNLocator` - it looks like if you create one, you can call its `view_limits` method, and then you can feed it to `contour` as the `locator` keyword argument

Comment: 'feed it to `contour` as the `locator` keyword argument',  Did you mean using it in levels argument of contour? Could you elaborate it even more or write a few lines of code as an example. I tried using it but couldn't proceed. I am not able to understand how to code this part.

Comment: So in the same way you say `levels = ` blah blah blah, you'd say `locator = ` blah blah blah.... are you familiar with using keyword arguments in python?

Comment: I have never used keywords argument in python. I am at the very beginning stage of coding. I tried coding for this part. If you help with a few lines of code in this regard it would be a great help.  I also referred to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/50824015/16319933, in this answer the filled contour is limited between a certain range rather than being completely filled. I somewhat want the same thing but with contour lines. @AJ Biffl

Comment: If you're a beginner, SO is probably not the best place for you to find answers. There are many tutorials available online if you need further help. As to the question you linked, replacing `contourf` with `contour` will do the same thing, but with contour lines instead of filled contours. When in doubt of what something is doing, it's always a good idea to [RTFM](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html)