# Control vmin and vmax in Iris 'animate'?

Tags: python, animation, python-iris

Does anyone know how (if?) I can control the `vmin` and `vmax` of an Iris quickplot pcolormesh animation using `iris.experimental.animate.animate`?

```
wind = iris.load_cube('/my/pp/file')
cube_iter = wind.slices(('longitude', 'latitude'))
ani = animate(cube_iter, qplt.contourf,vmin=0,vmax=20)
plt.show()
```

I'm using Iris version 2.4.0.

In this code, the animation works, but vmax is ignored (see attached screenshot).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

[image: Image illustrating that vmax is not being obeyed.]

Comment: I did a little digging, and I think this might ultimately be an instance of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823771/colorbar-does-not-apply-vmin-and-vmax?rq=1.  Though the fix would need to be in Iris rather than your code.  Feel free to open an issue and/or pull request over on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a fudge, but we can produce a more sensible animation by using the [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function to fix the `levels` and `extend` keyword.

```
import functools

import iris
from iris.experimental.animate import animate
import iris.quickplot as qplt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_contourf = functools.partial(qplt.contourf, levels=range(260, 291, 5),
                                extend="both")
# Function defined by partial has no __module__ or __name__ attribute, so add
# them to get past iris animate's checks.
my_contourf.__module__ = "iris.quickplot"
my_contourf.__name__ = "contourf"

fname = iris.sample_data_path("E1_north_america.nc")
cube = iris.load_cube(fname)[:20]

cube_iter = cube.slices(('longitude', 'latitude'))
ani = animate(cube_iter, my_contourf, vmin=260, vmax=290)
ani.save("abc.gif")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for this, brilliant! the gif is saved and animates as shown. one thing though, i am using jupyter and this doesn't animate inside the notebook. does this work for you? thanks again!

Comment: It works in a notebook for me if I put your `%matplotlib notebook` at the start.

Comment: perfect! works now that you pointed this out haha! thanks :)